maximal length of saturated chains with a given terminal point in the lattice of partitions of an integer ordered by dominance
Let $Pr(n)$ be the set of partitions of the positive integer $n$. This is a lattice with respect to the dominance order: if $\lambda=(\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots)$, $\mu=(\mu_1\geq\mu_2\geq\cdots)\in Pr(n)$, then
$\lambda\geq\mu$ if $\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i$ for all $k$. It is  well-known that $Pr(n)$ is not graded if $n>6$.
To my best knowledge the properties of this lattice was first systematically investigated by Brylawski in "Discrete Mathematics, vol 6, (1973), 201-209". For example, $\lambda$ covers $\mu$ (i.e., $\lambda>\mu$ and there does not exist a $\nu$ such that $\lambda>\nu>\mu$) iff there exist two positive integers $i<j$ such that $\lambda_i=\mu_i+1$, $\lambda_j=\mu_j-1$, $\lambda_k=\mu_k$ if $k\neq i,j$, and either $j=i+1$ or $\mu_i=\mu_j$.
Given $\lambda\in Pr(n)$, denote $r(\lambda)$ to be the maximum of all lengths of the saturated chains in $Pr(n)$ whose terminal element is $\lambda$, i.e.
$$r(\lambda)=\max\{l~|~\text{there exists a saturated chain $x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_{l-1}<\lambda$}\}.$$
My question is, is there an "explicit" formula for $r(\lambda)$? If not, is there any explicit lower bound for it? Many thanks in advance!
